# Fail to check item hover using jquery / js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

There is a menu button (#menu_product) when user 's mouse is over it , the menu will slide down (#about). However, it can not check the condition to slide up (hide) it. The logic is I need to ensure both the button and menu is not hovered then slide up. But it seems the menu never slide up , how to fix it? Thanks

```
$('#menu_product').live('mouseout',function() {
    if (!$('#about:hover')) {
        $("#about").slideUp("slow");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following to get effect you are trying to achieve

```
$("#menu_product, #about").hover(
  function () {
    $("#about").stop();
    $("#about").slideDown("slow");
  }, 
  function () {
    $("#about").slideUp("slow");
  }
);
```

​Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/np67k/

Comment: sorry , but it seems there is no condition? it will slidedown and slide up immediately?

Comment: it will slide up when menu_product is not hover, menu is hover.

Comment: Thanks for making fiddle, when the mouse over test content , it will slide up and it suppose not to slide up

Comment: It wont slide up when you hover on test content.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript `$('#about:hover')` will always return a valid jquery object, so will always be true.

Try using something like `$('#about').is(':hover')` instead, as the `.is()` function returns a boolean. http://api.jquery.com/is/

Comment: In that case you might have to apply a class or other identifier to the about menu so that it can be easily tested. Or try ":visible"

Answer (score 0):

#1 do not use `live`, it is deprecated.

Try this:

```
$('#menu_product').on('mouseout',function() {
    var $about = $('#about').toggleClass('.hover');
    if (!$about.is('.hover')) {
        $about.slideUp("slow");
    }
});
```

Comment: not working as well... perharps is hover condition is not useable?

Comment: @user782104 yea I cant help you without knowing what the HTML looks like. please post a fiddle demo.